# Bash terminal trying to read a previously installed file on each start up

Tags: bash, fedora, terminal, gnome, gnome-terminal

Whenever I open the (Gnome) terminal from my Fedora 26 system this line is being displayed first before the command prompt:

> -bash: /home/kiran/AIPS/LOGIN.SH: No such file or directory

I understand that on each start up the terminal is trying to read the above mentioned file.  I find this irritating.  Why is this happening?

(PS: *AIPS* was a software I had installed previously.  After installing it I was not being able to open the system settings.  The installation was incorrectly overriding the system libraries and hence I removed it.  This warning that I am getting seems to be an artifact from that AIPS installation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [one person's installation guide](https://home.strw.leidenuniv.nl/~ims/aips.html) I suspect you have an AIPS-related line in your `~/.bashrc` file; edit that file and remove the line that reads something like:

```
. ~/AIPS/LOGIN.SH
```

It could use variations such as:

```
source ~/AIPS/LOGIN.SH
```

or

```
source $HOME/AIPS/LOGIN.SH
```

Search for the text `AIPS/LOGIN.SH` and you should find the right spot.